# connect Android with PHP, MySQL , unfortunately app has stopped in android emulator

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to write this [tuto](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) When I run the app in the emulator,in the last step ,  it gives the message Unfortunately, app has Stopped.
I have no compile time errors.
and this is my logcat code

```
05-02 20:38:17.787    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-02 20:38:18.076    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
05-02 20:38:18.276    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
05-02 20:38:18.376    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-02 20:38:18.486    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-02 20:38:18.566    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php W/System.err﹕ ... 21 more
05-02 20:38:18.726    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 20:38:18.736    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
05-02 20:38:18.977    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-02 20:38:19.977    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.ghazi.php.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:98)
        at com.example.ghazi.php.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:63)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-02 20:38:22.767    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 20:38:22.877    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 20:38:23.267    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 20:38:23.907    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 20:38:23.947    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 20:38:24.186    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php E/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
05-02 20:38:24.249    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 20:38:24.647    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 20:38:24.917    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 20:38:25.437    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 20:38:25.467    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 20:38:25.867    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php E/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
05-02 20:38:25.957    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 20:38:26.247    1374-1379/com.example.ghazi.php I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 20:38:27.456    1374-1374/com.example.ghazi.php E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.ghazi.php.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41671100 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.ghazi.php.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41671100 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
        at com.example.ghazi.php.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:75)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
        at com.example.ghazi.php.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:55)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 20:41:08.987    1374-1389/com.example.ghazi.php I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1374 SIG: 9
```

Comment: this permission exist in my manifest file

Comment: (Without having looked to much at that tutorial) Are you trying to run your wamp server and your android emulator at the same time? 

I've had experience where trying to run a virtual machine & the android emulator causes the emulator to crash.

Comment: Show what you have got in NewProductActivity.java line __98__

Comment: this is line 98 in  NewProductActivityt             Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

Comment: @jwv yes i tried run at the same time , because the apache server it is mandatory to open